# Access to iPod musics

Tags: system, sharing

I am trying to access my music in iPod touch but I can access only photos and documents.

I can see to iPod using "Pantheon" and "Clementine" but I can not find any music using them.

How do I get to my music?

Comment: How did you put the music on the ipod? Through iTunes?

Comment: Hi, I used iTunes long time ago.

Comment: In that case I don't think yo will be able to access the music. Should be possible to reformat and put music on the iPod from Linux though. I'm not putting this as an answer just in case things have improved since I last tried this.